# IntentService not called from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-intentservice

I am calling a broadcast receiver from class FragmentA -

**FragmentA:**

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    Log.i(TAG, "------onReceive BroadcastReceiver------");

    streamContext = context;

   for(int i = 0; i< 3;i++)
   {
     startSpeedInt = i;

     Intent msgIntent = new Intent(streamContext, triggerService.class);

     msgIntent.putExtra("startSpeedInt", startSpeedInt);

     streamContext.startService(msgIntent);
   }
}
```

The triggerService is a service -

**triggerService:**

```
public class triggerService extends IntentService{

    public triggerService() {
        super("triggerService");
        mHandler = new Handler();
        ctx = this;
    }

    @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

            Log.i(TAG, "----onHandleIntent triggerService Started----");
    }
       //more code here
}
```

**Manifest entry:**

```
<service android:name="com.testapp.main.triggerService" />
```

I noticed that my code never reaches the triggerService because the Log message is not getting printed out.

Can we not queue the call to IntentService each time we increment variable i ?

Comment: Have you specified your service in the manifest file? I suppose you're extending IntentService?

Comment: Yes my service is in a manifest file and then in code I am extending the `IntentService`. See update.

Comment: Have you implemented a constructor that calls super("WorkerThreadName"); ?

Comment: yes its there. See update.

Comment: Did you override anything else in the IntentService? (maybe forgetting to call super in the process)

Comment: Do you have any filters in your LogCat on?

Comment: Would like to see how you are initializing streamContext.

Comment: @NemanjaMaksimovic - No, not anything else. There is only one call to super in the process `super("triggerService");` as you see in my code.

Comment: Ok, _//more code here_ suggested there could be more code :) Did you try invoking it just once, without for loop. I'm throwing wild guesses, but your code looks as if it should work, so let's eliminate all we can...

Comment: @beworker - The problem is - I am seeing the call to service just fine with the same code but not my client. However he is using actual real time data to be sent to the Service from `FragmentA`. And I hardcoded my data and multiple calls to that Service depends on that data frequency.

Comment: @Darpan - StreamContext is just a context from receiver. See update.

Comment: You may need to cast this context in some activity or may want to get base context out of it, so that it could start an intent service. May be with the activity that started fragment A. ((MyApplication)mContext.getApplicationContext()).startService(service);